# Hamiltonian flow local diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I am currently reading Arnold's proof of the Darboux theorem in his book on classical mechanics and fail to understand some point.

**The background**
So he wants to show that any symplectic form is locally (in a neighbourhood of some $x$) $$\omega = \sum_{i=1}^{n} dp_i \wedge dq_i.$$
It's on p. 230 in his book on classical mechanics.
Now, we says that the first coordinate can be chosen as a non-constant linear function $p_1$. Now, we pick the one that satisfies $p_1(x)=0.$

Since there is a canonical isomorphism between tangent and cotangent space in symplectic geometry, we can get a vector field $P_1 = I dp_1.$ Now since $dp_1$ is non-trivial $P_1(x) \neq 0.$ This is a proper vector in the tangent space at the point $x$ and hence we can consider the orthogonal complement $N^{2n-1}$ to it.

Now, I am getting a little bit confused: He says, consider the hamiltonian flow $P_1^t$ with Hamilton function $p_1.$ We consider the time necessary to go from $N$ (I guess this is $N^{2n-1}$) to the point $z = P_1^t(y)$ for $y \in N.$ Under the action of $P_1^t$ as a function of the point $z$. By the usual theorems in the theory of ODEs, this function is defined and differentiable in a neighbourhood of the point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}.$ Denote it by $q_1.$

**My understanding**So let me summarize: He says that there is a function $q_1$ that measures the time it takes to go from the hypersurface $N^{2n-1}$ to any point $z$ in the local neighbourhood and he says that this function is properly defined locally?

**The question** Could anybody explain why we can reach any point locally and i.e. why we cannot reach a point on several ways at different times (if we can, maybe we take the shortest time, but anyway.) I would really love to see a motivation for this construction or some additional remarks.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental fact about smooth vector fields is that if $x$ is any point where $P_1(x)\ne 0$, there exist smooth coordinates $(u^1,\dots,u^n)$ defined on a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in which $P_1$ has the coordinate representation $\partial/\partial u^1$, and hence its flow is given by 
$$P_1^t(t,(u^1,\dots,u^n)) = (u^1+t,u^2,\dots,u^n).$$ 
(See, for example, my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.), Theorem 9.22.)

Arnold is a little unclear about the exact definition of his hypersurface $N$, but evidently what he means to say is that we can take $N$ to be the smooth hypersurface in $M$ given by the "orthogonal complement" to $P_1(x)$ in coordinates, not a hyperplane in the tangent space. (He also remarks that we could have taken $N$ to be any surface transverse to $P_1(x)$.)

In our coordinates $(u^1,\dots,u^n)$, therefore, we can take $N$ to be the hypersurface defined by $u^1=0$. Shrinking $U$ if necessary, we can also assume that $U$ is a coordinate cube of the form $\{u: |u|<c\}$ for some $c>0$. Then we can reach any point $u=(u^1,\dots,u^n)\in U$ by flowing from the point $(0,u^2,\dots,u^n)\in N$ for time $u^1$, and this is the only integral curve starting on $N$ that stays in $U$ and reaches $u$.  The "time necessary to go from $N$ to an arbitrary point in $U$" is just the coordinate function $u^1$, which is well defined and smooth in $U$.

(BTW, a small matter of notation: It's very common in differential geometry to introduce a manifold of dimension $k$ by saying "Let $M^k$ be a manifold." This is to be read as a shorthand for "Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $k$." The superscript $k$ is not part of the name of the manifold, and is typically omitted after the first mention. This is why Arnold switched from $N^{2n-1}$ to $N$.)